# Why does Github list Django's total lines of code as over 800K?

Tags: django, lines-of-code

https://github.com/django/django/graphs/code-frequency

It can't be that big can it? I've seen it listed elsewhere as only about 80k:

http://thegarywilson.com/blog/2012/software-metrics-django-case-study/

Answer (score 2):

I expect that includes translations: there are 71 different locales for all the template and Javascript code for the various contrib apps (admin, comments, etc).